# is there any rule about context menu nesting best practices . 

Tags: winforms, user-interface, contextmenu

i started working on an app and when you right click on a grid, you get about 14 menu items.  i thought it was cleaner to start to nest some of the menus as there were clean "grouping" of menu items but it caused a bit of debate.

is there some guideline or best UI practice on context menus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say maximum one level of nesting. And nesting only for rarely used actions, its a major hassle to use, especially for inexperienced users (i.e. your grandma).

Comment: nested mouseover menu's are idd user unfriendly. Try to keep 1 at most

Comment: to be clear, by two levels I mean the base level + subgroups. Not subgroups of subgroups :)

Answer (score 1):

A submenu requires extra clicks or mouse movement and **should be your last resort**. And the mouse movement required really is tricky; you have to move the mouse over that narrow strip of one menu item to the right, to get to the submenu.

Also, a submenu hides the item that the user may have been looking for, whereas normally it would have been in plain sight.

14 items isn't that much; for reference, my Firefox context menu contains 14 elements and I can find what I want real quickly. It is much better to group the items sensibly, with some separators in between, and maybe add clarifying icons.